When should I prefer text-propeties to pattern-matching for highlighting?
What are text-properties for?
I've gone through some of :help text-properties.
I guess the key is here

The main use for text properties is to highlight text.  This can be seen as a
replacement for syntax highlighting.  Instead of defining patterns to match
the text, the highlighting is set by a script, possibly using the output of an
external parser.  This only needs to be done once, not every time when
redrawing the screen, thus can be much faster, after the initial cost of
attaching the text properties.

but I can't really say I understand what are the reasons why I should choose the text-properties approach over the pattern approach for adding some highlighting; or vice-versa, fwiw.
What factors should I consider when choosing which strategy to choose, when I want to add syntax coloring to "something"?

The key sentence in the paragraph you quoted is the last one:

This only needs to be done once, not every time when redrawing the screen, thus can be much faster, after the initial cost of attaching the text properties.

With the "classic" mechanism, Vim goes through the whole lot of patterns that make up the current syntax each time the screen is redrawn, which can happen many times per second.
With text properties, you get more control over what happens and when, asynchronously or not, with or without the help of some external parser.
If you find the classic mechanism too slow or resource-intensive for your application, then text properties might be an interesting alternative.
Another difference is that the classic mechanism makes heavy use of regular expressions while text properties don't.
If you are somewhat allergic to regular expressions or you find that the engine's inherent limitations are a blocker, then text properties offer you an escape hatch by letting you define and implement your own logic however you want it.
And then there's how the classic mechanism is tied to filetypes and such when text properties are not.
Etc.
A thorough reading of :help text-properties will give you more ideas.
Now, the freedom given to you by text properties comes at a price. The classic mechanism is all built-in so all you have to do is define a number of rules while text properties force you to do all the heavy lifting yourself. The samples given in the doc are quite trivial, though, and you might eat more than you can chew.

By heavy lifting you mean things like "if I delete a line where I've made a word in the middle Error via text properties, and then put the line back, I have to manually reapply the text property because it got lost when I deleted the line"?

That, yes. But also maintaining your own grammar, writing your own parser or a bridge to an existing standalone parser, etc. Those things can go from trivial to hugely complex quickly. The task is not impossible, mind you, but it is still a far cry from the handful of regexp patterns needed for the classic mechanism.

Well my usecase is precisely this. Where would you say that is located on the spectrum between trivial and hugely complex?

With the provided information, I would say "pretty trivial" but advice is cheap.
